# Named Credentials not working with Twitter API

Tags: callout, oauth, post, twitter

So I have set up a Named Credentials with information about my Twitter App. I know the authentication is working correctly becacause my named credential looks like this:
[image]

And it says I am authenticated as my twitter account.

Here is my code to make a twitter api request:

```
public static void sendHttpPostRequest(string url)
{
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setTimeout(2000); //2 seconds
    req.setBody('');
    try
    {
        res = h.send(req);
        system.debug('HTTP-DEBUG: Sent POST request successfully');
        system.debug(('reponse is ' + res.getBody()));
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        system.debug('HTTP-DEBUG: Failed to send post request due to ' + e);
        system.debug(res.toString());
    }
}
```

When I try and post a status to my twitter account using:

```
HttpUtility.sendHttpPostRequest('callout:TwitterAPI/statuses/update.json?status=this%20is%20a%20test');
```

I get the following response from twitter:

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}
```

Any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143985/twitter-api-error-215

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'm a little confused about what I'm supposed to get from it? It appears to be about API requests that are non authenticated - however salesforce should be authenticating my request

Comment: based on the status code, it doesnt look like it. try debugging your code and check what header you are sending

Comment: When I debug my code(even after getting the response) I don't see any headers sent. I believe the headers are automatically set in the http.send method(along with converting the endpoint to the correct endpoint: 'https://api.twitter.com/TwitterAPI/statuses/update.json?status=this%20is%20a%20test'. In the name credentials page it says: 'if selected, the named credential generates and authorization header and applies it to each callout that references the named credential'. And since The named credential is being invoked(since I get a response from twitter) the headers must be set